# Zigbee interview process - xbee

Tags: xbee, micropython, zigbee

I have a zigbee2mqtt / home assistant setup working fine, and I'd like to try to make my own simple devices to connect to that network.
I got an xbee 3 board, and using micropython to start with I was able to connect to my network.

However the "interview" fails. The xbee receives a message with a cluster 0, profile 260 (home automation) and endpoint 230 (command). Not sure what the payload contains, that's not a string :

```
{'profile': 260, 'dest_ep': 230, 'broadcast': False, 'sender_nwk': 0, 'source_ep': 1, 'payload': b'\x10\x02\x00\x05\x00\x04\x00\x07\x00', 'sender_eui64': b"\x00\x12K\x00\x18\xe2I'", 'cluster': 0}
```

My question is what should I answer for the interview to succeed ?
I'm making only a basic sensor, I'd like to just report 1 weight reading periodically. I'm assuming I need to send back something saying I have one endpoint, on some cluster (not sure which, I guess something in the 400s) but I don't know what the format should be.

I couldn't find much info on this (baring how to use things like the Zigbee Cluster Library, which aren't python), any pointers or examples of end devices I could take a look at to understand how this interview process works ?

Unfortunately digi's examples all seem to involve xbee devices talking to each other, I couldn't find any examples of how to make a regular end device.

Thanks !

EDIT: Just found [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20180218010916/https://www.falco.co.nz/electronic-projects/xbee-to-smartthings/) great page which explains how this all works. Still need to figure out the exact bits I'll need and try it out, but now I know where to start !

Comment: According to this github issue, the firmware doesn't support it in micropython mode yet : https://github.com/digidotcom/xbee-micropython/issues/37#issuecomment-614288855

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a lot like the ZCL, and I'm not aware of an Open Source Python implementation of that protocol.  Digi has an [Open Source ANSI C Library](https://github.com/digidotcom/xbee_ansic_library) that includes a ZCL implementation.  If you can read C code, you might be able to decode that payload to see what it's asking.  You might also need to handle some of the ZDO/ZDP (Zigbee Data Object/Device Profile) protocol on endpoint 0, by setting ATAO=3 (IIRC).  There's also ZDO/ZDP code in that C library.  (Full disclosure: I wrote most of the code in that library, including the Zigbee layer.  But I haven't worked with Zigbee in a long time, so I'm rusty on protocol details.)

My recommendation would be to just hardcode hand-generated responses as much as possible.  Figure out the expected format for requests, and determine what works as a response.  If you can sniff the 802.15.4 traffic, or have your zigbee2mqtt gateway log activity with an existing device, you might be able to use its responses as a starting point for your implementation.